# URL Rewriting in asp.net from sub directory

Tags: url-rewriting

Can anybody tell me , how to Redirect a url in asp.net 4.0, I have a http based url and  the start page call Home.aspx is inside the directory. I want to use just domainname.com . please  suggest me how I can handle this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need URL rewriting for that.

`Administrative Tools -> IIS Manager -> You server name -> Your site name -> Under HTTP features -> Default document -> Add "Home.aspx"`

Or via Web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <add value="Home.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Home.aspx page is under sub folder and site is hosted on place of Default web site in IIS 7.5 , so it is not working properly. and current url is domainname/foldername/Home.aspx , I have assign the Name Home.aspx in default document   , but it is not working

Comment: Then have a look [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/68497/how-do-you-configure-iis-7-to-use-a-subdirectory-as-the-default-document), and try the suggestions.

Comment: Didn't found any reliable information , Actually my site is hosted on Default web site in IIS , and when I enter url then it is open IIS page .

Comment: in url here is Home.aspx bind many times and page is not going to open.

Comment: Answer: Worked Without doing anything , just delete the old directory and create new Virtual Directory and set Home.aspx as default page .